# How can I stop an automatic scrolling function whenever the mouse wheel moves?

Tags: javascript, scroll, mouse, mousewheel

I have a site where the page scrolls slowly automatically through this script:

```
function jumpScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0,1);
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('jumpScroll()',10);
}
```

I want the automatic scroll to stop whenever anyone moves the mouse wheel.

Any sort of advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming scrolldelay is a global variable in this context you can call clearTimeout

```
clearTimeout(scrolldelay);
```

This should cause the timeout to no longer fire.

You would just have to put this where ever you are catching the mousewheel event.